# How is black hole formed after a supernova explosion?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, supernova, stellar-evolution

Does all the mass of a core collapsing star get scattered during a supernova explosion? If it does, then how can a black hole be formed without any remaining mass? Or are there remnants of the star after supernova which would become a black hole?

Comment: There are several types of supernova, some leave a remnant, either a neutron star or black hole, some just blow the star apart. Neutron stars do not explode.

Comment: BTW, @DanYand another type that can leave no remnant is the [pair instability supernova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair-instability_supernova).

Comment: please read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova#Core_collapse

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/407854/2451 and links threrein.